# Hypergeometric Function Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there some nice obvious way to see that the hypergeometric function $$_2F_1(a,b;c:z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \tfrac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\tfrac{z^n}{n!}$$
should satisfy the differential equation

$$z(1-z)\tfrac{d^2u}{dz^2} + [c-(a+b+1)]\tfrac{du}{dz}-abu=0?$$

I can't get it to work out by directly differentiating & it's driving me crazy - can it be done directly or does it require some nice identity? Thanks

Comment: With your formula you will run into trouble, the DE should be
$$z(1-z)u''(z) + (c-(a+b+1))u'(z)-abu(z)=.0$$
For a derivation see e.g. Lebedev, Special functions, Sect. 7.2 _The Hypergeometric Equation and Its Series Solution_

Comment: Apologies, the first $u'$ should have been $u''$ - fixed. Unfortunately Lebedev plugs in a series solution to the given hypergeometric differential equation, whereas I'd like to use the hypergeometric series as a means of deriving the differential equation. I'm hoping there's a nice way of using the series to re-derive the differential equation, at least for thinking purposes.

Comment: Incidentally: it should be (a+b+1)*x :)

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to simplify!

We can apply the ``Method of Coefficients'';{http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.231.6616&rep=rep1&type=pdf}{Method of Coefficients}
.

We are looking for a recursion between terms; and then using the
Method of Coefficients to translate it into a differential equation.

Some excerpts from Method of Coefficients

$[x^{n}]x^{k}f(x)=[x^{n-k}]f(t)$ ;

$[x^{n}]\frac{f(x)}{x^{k}}=[x^{n+k}]f(x)$

$[x^{n}]n\cdot f(x)=[x^{n-1}]f'(x)=[x^{n}]f'(x)\cdot x$

Now writing down the relationship between successive coefficients
of

$_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;x)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(a\right)_{n}\left(b\right)_{n}}{\left(c\right)_{n}}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$

$[x^{n+1}]f(x)=\frac{\left(a+n\right)\cdot\left(b+n\right)}{\left(c+n\right)}\cdot\frac{n!}{\left(n+1\right)!}\cdot[x^{n}]f(x)=\frac{\left(a+n\right)\cdot\left(b+n\right)}{\left(c+1\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)}\cdot[x^{n}]f(x)$

$\left(n+1\right)\cdot\left(c+n\right)\cdot[x^{n+1}]f(x)-\left(a+n\right)\cdot\left(b+n\right)\cdot[x^{n}]f(x)=0$

$\left(c+n\right)\cdot[x^{n}]f'(x)-\left(a+n\right)\cdot b\cdot[x^{n}]f(x)-(a+n)\cdot[x^{n}]x\cdot f'(x)=0$

$[x^{n}]x\cdot f''(x)+c\cdot[x^{n}]f'(x)-b\cdot[x^{n}]x\cdot f'(x)-a\cdot b[x^{n}]f(x)-a\cdot[x^{n}]x\cdot f'(x)-[x^{n}]x^{2}\cdot f''(x)-[x^{n}]f'(x)=0$

$[x^{n}]\left(x-x^{2}\right)\cdot f''(x)+\left(c-\left(b+a+1\right)\cdot x\right)\cdot f'(x)-a\cdot b\cdot f(x)=0$

QED